# GIT Rebase in a new branch

Tags: git, rebase, cherry-pick

I want to do a pull in GitHub and want to perform a GIT Rebase to clean up intermediate commits before issuing a pull request. I want to know if the following procedure is proper.

While I'm pretty sure no one is building on top of my branch, for future references, I want to avoid rewriting history (avoid pulling the rug out from under others). I'm thinking of a cherry-pick procedure like the following (assuming my feature branch is called "feature_branch").
Note that my intention for the original feature_branch is to note that it is now abandoned.

1. Create a new branch from the head of master, something like "feature_pull_rebase"
2. Replay all commits (cherry-pick) from the "feature_branch" onto the "feature_pull_rebase"
3. Make pull request from the "feature_pull_request" onto master.

Is this a proper way to handle this? Or is there some danger with this?

EDIT: The master branch is not under my control, it's a repository I want to contribute to.

Comment: I would like to understand you question better. What are you afraid will happen when you rebase?

Comment: @mrrusof My understanding is that rebase is like reset, in that it destroys commit histories. I don't want to run the risk that when I rebase, I wipe out the commits that other developer are depending on.

Comment: @SterlingW are you trying to `sync a fork`? Can this help: https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/ ?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Technically yes. However, some repo maintainers have policy to minimize the amount of merges and request for a rebased version so you don't get a bunch of merge commit for a fairly long feature branch (I think it was Leaflet who asked me to do that once). In short, sync creates a merge if it can't fast-forward, and I want to eliminate merges (and potentially allow the master to fast forward the pull into it).

Comment: @SterlingW I understand, then follow the instructions from the link in my comment, but in step 5 do a `git rebase` and you'll be good.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Thank you. I do understand how to rebase. My current understanding is that rebase destroy commit history, I want to know whether I'm wrong or if the procedure I used in my question would help minimize the change of me destroying commit histories that other developer are basing their changes on.

Comment: Your procedure is okay. `git pull --rebase <remote> master` also works. So does `git rebase master feature_pull_rebase`, which I need to have a test. I personally prefer `git cherry-pick` or `git merge --ff-only`.